# Returning array of objects from static function

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I am making a *basic* Visual Studio project.
Easiest way to explain is to show the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int amountOfCars = getAmountOfCars();
            Car[] myCars = createCars(amountOfCars);

        }

        public static int getAmountOfCars (){
            Console.WriteLine("Amount of Cars to enter");
            int amountOfCars = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            return amountOfCars;
        }


        public static Car createCars(int amountOfCars)

        {
            Car[] myCars = new Car[amountOfCars];
            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCars; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter brand");
                string brand = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of wheels");
                int amountOfWheels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of seats");
                int amountOfSeats = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                myCars[i] = new Car(brand, amountOfWheels, amountOfSeats);
            }
            return myCars[amountOfCars];

        }
    }
}
```

This line

```
 Car[] myCars = createCars(amountOfCars);
```

Throws the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type testing.Car to testing.Car[]

So, I then tried this to convert over

```
 Car[] myCars = (Car[]) createCars(amountOfCars);
```

But it still throws the error.

Essentially I am just trying to return the `array` of `objects` from `createcar` function, so that it can be used within the rest of the code.

What is the best practice to solve this?

Comment: `Car createCars(` returns a single `Car`, not an array

Comment: So How would I make it return an array?

Comment: To be honest I'm surprised that it's not throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. `return myCars[amountOfCars];`, since it appears you're appear to have an "off by one" error. The last element in the array is `myCars[amountOfCars-1];`

Comment: @phuzi It would throw that exception, if it compiled....

Comment: @phuzi It's not because that would only happen when running the code, but currently it doesn't even compile because of the type mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the function is

```
public static Car createCars(int amountOfCars)
```

instead of

```
public static Car[] createCars(int amountOfCars)
```

Also return just the array

```
return myCars;
```

instead of

```
return myCars[amountOfCars]; // This returns only one object at the amountOfCars index in the myCars array.
```

Also, this will trigger the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as the `myCars` is allocated for `amountOfCars` and array spans from `myCars[0]` to `myCars[amountOfCars-1]`

Comment: Since `amountOfCars` is the size of the array that does not return anything, it would result in an index out of range exception.

Comment: Yes.. Sorry My Bad. I just wanted to say the OP that returning as in allocation will not return all the array. I will update appropriately. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 5):

You need to return an array from createCars():

```
public static Car[] createCars(int amountOfCars)

    {
        Car[] myCars = new Car[amountOfCars];
        for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCars; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter brand");
            string brand = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of wheels");
            int amountOfWheels = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter amount of seats");
            int amountOfSeats = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            myCars[i] = new Car(brand, amountOfWheels, amountOfSeats);
        }
        return myCars;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

funcion

```
public static int[] addFirst(int value, int count, int[] test) 
{
    test = test.Where(val => val != value).ToArray();
    Array.Resize(ref test, test.Length + 1);

        for (int i = count-1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            test[i] = test[i-1];
        }
         test[0] = value;
    
    return test;
}
```

declaracion

```
array= addFirst(value, array.Length, array);
```

Comment: You should add some text and explain what your answer does and why it answers the question